# ReactJS - method won't run after fetch

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code as part of a login function:

```js
handleClick(event){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8000/login/loginuser/';
    const form = new FormData()
    form.set('username', this.state.userName)
    form.set('password', this.state.password)
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form,
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      alert(responseJson)
    })
}
```

My expectation is that, when the function is run, an alert will pop up with the response returned by the POST request using the Fetch API.

Instead, nothing happens. (The POST request goes through and is received by the backend).

Why is the alert code not running after fetch is finished?

Comment: Add a .catch() to check if there's an error happening. response.json may not be a method

Comment: Maybe it fails to parse the response to json, try to add a `.catch` statement